# How does one install camlp5 compatible with version 4.05.0 of ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, coq, camlp4

I was trying to install tcoq and gamepad as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926584/ocaml-and-preprocessor-have-incompatible-versions-error-when-installing-tcoq) but had the errors:

```
make
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make --warn-undefined-variable --no-builtin-rules -f Makefile.build
OCAMLC -c -pp grammar/gramCompat.mlp
>> Fatal error: OCaml and preprocessor have incompatible versions
Fatal error: exception Misc.Fatal_error
make[1]: *** [grammar/gramCompat.cmo] Error 2
make: *** [submake] Error 2
```

so I discovered that I had the wrong version of `campl5`:

```
$ camlp5 -v
Camlp5 version 7.07 (ocaml 4.07.0)
```

since the one I need is the one compatible with ocaml `4.05.0` according to [gamepad](https://github.com/ml4tp/gamepad) and [tcoq](https://github.com/ml4tp/tcoq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install an OCaml package compatible with a given version of OCaml, I would suggest you use `opam`. By looking at [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926584/ocaml-and-preprocessor-have-incompatible-versions-error-when-installing-tcoq), I assume it is already the case.

In order to install the correct version of `camlp5` for the active switch (i.e. for Ocaml `4.05.0` in your case), run the following command:

```
opam install camlp5
```

It will download the required dependencies and install it to your local `opam` installation folder.

This might however cause some issues if you already have another version of `camlp5` installed through your favorite packet manager (e.g. `brew`). See my answer to [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926584/ocaml-and-preprocessor-have-incompatible-versions-error-when-installing-tcoq) for more details.